# How to check if first five characters of one field match another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Assuming I have the following table:

```
AAAAAA
AAAAAB
CCCCCC
```

How could I craft a query that would let me know that `AAAAA` and `AAAAB` are similar (as they share five characters in a row)? Ideally I would like to write this as a query that would check if the two fields shared five characters in a row anywhere in the string but this seems outside the scope of SQL and something I should write into a C# application?

Ideally the query would add another column that displays: `Similar to 'AAAAA', 'AAAAB'`

Comment: how do they share five characters in a row? they only share 4, or do you mean the count of character?

Comment: Sorry, I made my example poorly (late Friday afternoon). Updating now

Comment: same here Friday afternoon, so i stay in SO; @Michael is there an input used for comparison or you just have a dataset and want to compare among themselves?

Comment: When you say your ideal would be to match anywhere, do you mean that the two strings should have five matching characters *at the same position*, or such that five characters at the start of one string would be a match for five characters at the end of the other?

Comment: The `SOUNDEX` and `DIFFERENCE` functions aren't really applicable to general pattern matching, but may be of some interest.

Comment: @user92546 Looks perfect! This will help a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you do not try to violate 1NF by introducing a multi-valued attribute.

Noting that `SUBSTRING` is highly portable:

```
WITH T 
     AS
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('AAAAAA'), 
                     ('AAAAAB'), 
                     ('CCCCCC')
             ) AS T (data_col)
     )
SELECT T1.data_col, 
       T2.data_col AS data_col_similar_to
  FROM T AS T1, T AS T2
 WHERE T1.data_col < T2.data_col
       AND SUBSTRING(T1.data_col, 1, 5) 
              = SUBSTRING(T2.data_col, 1, 5);
```

Alternativvely:

```
T1.data_col LIKE SUBSTRING(T2.data_col, 1, 5) + '%';
```

Answer (score 3):

This will find all matches, also those in the middle of the word, it will not perform well on a big table

```
declare @t table(a varchar(20))

insert @t select 'AAAAAA'
insert @t select 'AAAAAB'
insert @t select 'CCCCCC'
insert @t select 'ABCCCCC'
insert @t select 'DDD'

declare @compare smallint = 5

;with cte as
(
select a, left(a, @compare) suba, 1 h
from @t
union all
select a, substring(a, h + 1, @compare), h+1
from cte where cte.h + @compare <= len(a)
)
select t.a, cte.a match from @t t 
-- if you don't want the null matches, remove the 'left' from this join 
left join cte on charindex(suba, t.a) > 0 and t.a <> cte.a  
group by t.a, cte.a
```

Result:

```
a                    match
-------------------- ------
AAAAAA               AAAAAB
AAAAAB               AAAAAA
ABCCCCC              CCCCCC
CCCCCC               ABCCCCC
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) to compare the first five characters and you can use `for xml path` to concatenate the similar strings to one column.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  Col varchar(10)
)

insert into @T values
('AAAAAA'),
('AAAAAB'),
('AAAAAC'),
('CCCCCC')

select Col,
       stuff((select ','+T2.Col
              from @T as T2
              where left(T1.Col, 5) = left(T2.Col, 5) and
                    T1.ID <> T2.ID
              for xml path(''), type).value('.',  'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Similar
from @T as T1
```

Result:

```
Col        Similar
---------- -------------------------
AAAAAA     AAAAAB,AAAAAC
AAAAAB     AAAAAA,AAAAAC
AAAAAC     AAAAAA,AAAAAB
CCCCCC     NULL
```